# Why was Tom Bombadil so unconcerned about the fate of Middle-earth?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, tom-bombadil

I know he saves the hobbits from the barrow-wight and gives them weapons which affect the Nazgûl, Sauron's greatest servants. But I've always wondered why a high power, which Tom Bombadil obviously is, doesn't play a more significant part against Sauron. Gandalf says at the Council of Elrond that Tom wouldn't understand the struggle between Light and Darkness.

Asked if Bombadil might take the Ring for safekeeping, Gandalf replies:

> "No," said Gandalf, "not willingly. He might do so if all the free folk of the world begged him, but **he would not understand the need**. And if he were given the Ring, he would soon forget it, or most likely throw it away. **Such things have no hold on his mind**. He would be a most unsafe guardian; and that alone is answer enough."
>
> <sub>*The Fellowship of the Ring, Book II, Chapter 2: "The Council of Elrond"*.</sub>

What confuses me is that if Sauron regains the One Ring, Tom will also fall like the rest of Middle-earth.

**Is there any other info in the texts (aside from fact that Gandalf says that he basically doesn't care what happens) about why he didn't play a more prominent role?**

Comment: Tom appears to be above an beyond anything sauron could every be, so he has little interest in matters that wont affect him.

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate, im not asking if tom could personally defeat Sauron

Comment: @AndresF. I don't agree, unless you're thinking of the answer saying "Tom is a literary device, so no". Bombadil was uninterested in Sauron because he's beyond caring about "good" or "evil"; the answer to this question is not an answer to that one, and vice-versa

Comment: Perhaps it's that he really only cares about those that he has made his friends.  For a parallel, I care about my dogs, and would help a lost/injured dog if I ran across one while I was out walking, but I feel no need to go out and get involved in a dog rescue organization.

Comment: @user31546 - the quote:  "No," said Gandalf, "not willingly. He might do so, if all the free folk of the world begged him, but he would not understand the need. And if he were given the Ring, he would soon forget it, or most likely throw it away. Such things have no hold on his mind. He would be a most unsafe guardian; and that alone is answer enough."

Comment: @user31546 - and:  "Could we not still send messages to him and obtain his help?" asked Erestor. "It seems that he has a power even over the Ring."

"No, I should not put it so," said Gandalf. "Say rather that the Ring has no power over him. He is his own master. But he cannot alter the Ring itself, nor break its power over others. And now he is withdrawn into a little land, within bounds that he has set, though none can see them, waiting perhaps for a change of days, and he will not step beyond them."

Comment: @user31546 - and: 
"But in any case," said Glorfindel, "to send the Ring to him would only postpone the day of evil. He is far away. We could not now take it back to him, unguessed, unmarked by any spy. And even if we could, soon or late the Lord of the Rings would learn of its hiding place and would bend all his power towards it. Could that power be defied by Bombadil alone? I think not. I think that in the end, if all else is conquered, Bombadil will fall, Last as he was First; and then Night will come."

Comment: @user31546 - I decided to save you some work by adding the quote to your question myself.  Hope you don't mind!

Comment: On a lighter note, he has a hot wife and a nice house guarded by ferocious man-eating trees:  why should he care about anything else?  :)

Comment: It is wrong to think that Bombadil is a great power.  He confronts and defeats Old Man Willow and a Barrow-Wight through force of personality; it seems probable to me that the average Elf-warrior could have done the same through force of arms.  The Ring has no power over him; this is because he desires nothing the Ring has to offer, which is a feat of enlightenment (in the Buddhist sense), not power.  We have no reason to think he could, say, grapple with a Balrog as Gandalf did.

Comment: @wadcheber not at all, appreciated for adding it!

Comment: @zwol [And song!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZouiWmzWoY)

Comment: @zwol: Note Gandalf's statement: "I think that **in the end**, if **all else** is conquered, Bombadil will fall, Last **as he was First**; and then Night will come." -- Emphasis mine. There is quite some "power" implied here, though I am as smart as anyone as to its exact nature.

Comment: @DevSolar - Glorfindel says that, not Gandalf

Comment: Tom Bombadil leaves an idyllic, peaceful, and un-affiliated life.  He is the Switzerland of Middle Earth.

Comment: This is not a duplicate

Comment: Agreed, not sure why people are so quick to close questions as duplicates. Is there some kind of karma incentive? This is clearly distinct from "could he defeat Sauron" especially.

Comment: The above comment should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: My favorite answer is http://km-515.livejournal.com/1042.html

Comment: @zwol Nevertheless when he was first brought in (Tolkien had already invented him irrespective of Middle-earth) Bombadil was able to stop the mounted Barrow-wights (yes they were mounted and there was even the suggestion that they're related to if not actually the Nazgûl). Of course in The Fellowship he helps the hobbits in their plight with the Barrow-wights also. So if nothing else it wasn't just Old Man Willow. But if it had been that they were the Nazgûl it'd be far more impressive wouldn't it? Still they were sent by the Lord. The origin suggests me he's more powerful speculation or no.

Comment: @zwol Of course in the earlier draft he suggested to the hobbits that he knew Butterbur (although I can't recall that stayed when his name actually became that and neither can I recall if it ever happened after he was made human instead of hobbit). Gandalf also suggested he might want to summon him which suggests earlier on he would be more willing to be out of his land. Not that it really changes anything in the end; otoh I think it's equally speculative if not more so to say that any elf warrior could have dealt with Old Man Willow.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Tolkien addressed this in Letter 144:

> I might put it this way. The story is cast in terms of a good side, and a bad side, beauty against ruthless ugliness, tyranny against kingship, moderated freedom with consent against compulsion that has long lost any object save mere power, and so on; but both sides in some degree, conservative or destructive, want a measure of control. but if you have, as it were taken 'a vow of poverty', renounced control, and take your delight in things for themselves without reference to yourself, watching, observing, and to some extent knowing, then the question of the rights and wrongs of power and control might become utterly meaningless to you, and the means of power quite valueless. It is a natural pacifist view, which always arises in the mind when there is a war.
>
> <sup><sub>*The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien* 144: To Naomi Mitchison. April 1954</sub></sup>

Basically, Bombadil isn't interested in the threat of Sauron because he is entirely beyond caring about "good" or "evil". In fact, Tom Bombadil doesn't really care about anything beyond preserving the peace within his own borders; even that he only accomplishes with song and force of personality.

Bombadil is ultimately a complete pacifist, and has no use for violence or struggle against anyone, even "evil".

Comment: Take it this is the reason why he doesn't seem to care that old man willow resides in his boundaries until the tree decides to munch on merry and pip :p

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say that he doesn't care about good and evil (that is, that he doesn't care whether individuals behave in a good or evil manner); but he doesn't care about **making certain** that one side or the other in a "good versus evil" struggle wins.

Comment: I wonder if Tom actually knows that Sauron will be defeated without any further effort on his own part?  He is incredibly ancient and wise, after all - some people even think he might be Eru (the fact that these people are wrong doesn't change the fact that Tom might have access to information we don't).

Comment: @Wad: I would guess that he trusts that things will happen as is best in the long run, and if what is best happens to include his death and the destruction of his country, well, ring a dong dillo!

Comment: @Wad: or personification of Ea (the Earth) or nature.

Comment: So, if Bombadil is beyond caring about good and evil, can we call him a good character? Was his assistance to the hobbits equally amoral?

Comment: @curiousdannii Depends on your morals, I guess. I don't think we can call Bombadil "good" or "bad"; he's on nobody's side, because nobody is on his side. But I would still call his assistance to the Hobbits "good". Outcome exists independently of intent, as Gollum (and innumerable historical examples) showed us

Comment: Bombadil (as well as the ents) was also an analogy to neutral parties during WW2, as much as LotR lends itself to that analogy (which is to say that there are a lot of metaphors for real-life occurrences, but WW2 is not exclusively among them). His assertion was that if evil wins, neutral parties lose as well. paraphrasing pippin to the ents: But you're part of this world! Bombadil was largely a, I believe, swiss analogy. Both were very powerful, both could sway the war in one direction or another, and both seemed to not care. Had Sauron (Hitler) won the war, Bombadil (swiss) would also lose.

Comment: I might even go as far as to say that in Tolkiens universe, there is no grey-area, and he wanted to make that obvious with examples of characters that SEEMED neutral (grey) but were in fact good or evil. Orcs are deliberately evil, even in ways where it makes no sense to be, and are designed to be the ultimate evil force. The reader is not meant to question our heroe's killing of them, it simply isnt that kind of book. I digress though.

Comment: @TomSterkenburg -In the books, the Ents were never really opposed to entering the war

Comment: @TomSterkenburg - also, no one would have bothered Switzerland because the Swiss had everyone's money, and would have thrown interest rates into chaos if anyone messed with them.  Plus, no one was willing to fight a country composed entirely of narrow mountain roads and inhabited by sharpshooters.

Comment: Kaiser in WWI, to the leader of Switzerland:  "Your army is only 250,000 men strong.  What will they do if I send half a million men across your border?"  Swiss leader:  "Fire twice and go home". (Every man in Switzerland is obligated to serve in the military and bring his weapons home when his enlistment is over)

Comment: @TomSterkenburg LOTR is not a WWII allegory. I refer you to *the opening paragraph* of the Wikipedia article on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Themes_of_The_Lord_of_the_Rings

Comment: @NathanielFord good to know my point has no sway

Comment: A late comment, but (I hope) better than none: I think this is a solid answer, but needs to be noted that the extreme pacifism of Bombadil is not morally superior to (say) Gandalf's activism in taking down Sauron. Tom has *diminished* himself by declining moral choices. As Gandalf says, "And now he is withdrawn into a little land, within bounds that he has set, though none can see them, waiting perhaps for a change of days..."

Answer (score 8):

There are some assumptions you're making.

First, there is no real proof that Sauron will simply win if he gets the One Ring. Yes, all of his opponents believe this to be true... but of course they do! Sauron had the Ring in the past and was defeated: from an objective point of view there is no reason to believe that he would actually conquer the *entire* world. Or that that rule would last forever and be unchanging. It is conceivable that Bombadil simply can weather that storm: and that capability would in no way change Gandalf's assessment, since what Gandalf cares about would still be gravely affected.

Secondly, when Bombadil is described he is described as having been there at the creation of the world, before anything else. Perhaps he is a Maiar or Valar, or perhaps he is another entity entirely, existing tangentially to Middle Earth. That would explain how he could *already* be there at the creation. "Tom remembers the first raindrop and the first acorn [...] he knew the dark under the stars when it was fearless — before the Dark Lord came from Outside"

Thirdly, there is the assumption that Bombadil is actually a character in the story rather than one of a manifestation of aspects of the world itself that provided the simulacrum of a reasoning entity (nothing says, for instance, that the memory he remembers is his...) or a meta-character, a representation of the reader themselves: he can make the Ring "appear and disappear at will", much like someone who can open or close a book, or start or stop a story. Whether he is such a meta representation of the reader or an actual in-world entity, with such power why would he be concerned about Sauron? Given that he can see Frodo with the Ring on, perhaps he simply has the ability to ignore Sauron's power.

Suffice to say, Bombadil exists next to the Lord of the Rings, and it seems like a misdirection to attempt to ascribe motivations to him similar to the rest of the protagonists.

Comment: There were a lot more Elves and men in the world when Sauron was first defeated, and an alliance existed then, which is no longer the case.

Comment: @WadCheber *The strength of the Elves to resist him was greater long ago; and not all Men were estranged from them.* As far as the rest of the answer: I'd need a lot of evidence to indicate that Bombadil *wasn't* "a character in the story" rather than something more "postmodern"; I see no evidence that such is the case, and Tolkien never used such a device in any other of his stories or books.

Comment: Are we talking *author intent* or the possibilities *as presented by the text*? Arguably one of the benefits of quality literature is that those stories provide a plethora of ways to be read.

Comment: @MattGutting - you know this isn't my answer, right?

Comment: @WadCheber Yes, I just can't call out both you and Nathaniel in the same comment.

Comment: Nathaniel - I think there is such a thing as *authorial intent*; certainly there are "a plethora of ways" to read the text, but only some of them are reasonably compatible with authorial intent, and I think those are the **right** ways to read the text.

Comment: I am always cautious when someone says there is a 'right' way to read a text. Authorial intent is certainly an interesting aspect and enlightening in one way, but confining in another.

Answer (score 4):

This perhaps goes back to Socratic philosophy.  In it, [there's a concept of the "Ideal" and the "Physical"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_Forms) with the physical being a pale shadow implementation of what the "Ideal" is/can be.

> Plato's theory of Forms or theory of Ideas asserts that non-material abstract (but substantial) forms (or ideas), and not the material world of change known to us through sensation, possess the highest and most fundamental kind of reality. When used in this sense, the word form or idea is often capitalized. Plato speaks of these entities only through the characters (primarily Socrates) of his dialogues who sometimes suggest that these Forms are the only true objects of study that can provide us with genuine knowledge; thus even apart from the very controversial status of the theory,

My interpretation of Peter Kreeft's book [*Ethics: The History of Moral Thought*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001GKVBVK) is that Socrates believed that evil people could not "harm" a "good" person.  In this he did not think that evil couldn't inflict pain and damage upon the physical person of an individual, rather evil could not fundamentally alter the "Ideals" of that individual and therefore couldn't harm his moral essence.

If we consider Tom Bombadil as Tolkien's concept of the "Ideal", then Bombadil isn't worried about/interested in/concerned with Sauron and his evil.  Sauron can't harm the ideal and therefore isn't really relevant.

[Socrates even believed that people don't knowingly do harm](http://www.socraticmethod.net/socratic_essay_nature_of_human_evil.htm) (or evil).

> Socrates believed that nobody willingly chooses to do wrong. He maintained that doing wrong always harmed the wrongdoer and that nobody seeks to bring harm upon themselves. In this view all wrongdoing is the result of ignorance. This means that it is impossible for a human being to willingly do wrong because their instinct for self interest prevents them from doing so.

If you ascribe to Socratic philosophy than it makes perfect sense that Tom Bombadil's impression of Sauron (if he thought of Sauron at all) was as not relevant to Tom Bomadil and his interests.

Comment: Where are these quotes from? Are they quotes?

Comment: The quoted portions are from the sources I linked.  The other stuff is my interpretation of a set of lectures I got on audio book.

Comment: Fair enough. If you could cite the references that'd be great.

Comment: I know this concept was a stretch but Tom Bombadil's seeming indifference reminded me of Socrates' willingness to ingest Hemlock.  Tom nor Socrates worried about their ideals and not much else seemed important to them.

Comment: You have my +1.  I dunno where it went though.

Comment: Prob a down vote.  I just wish I knew why :)

Comment: @Jim2B - How do you think I feel?  I post pictures of a hot River-Daughter and I get 2 down votes for my trouble.  :(

Comment: Where did yours go?

Comment: @Jim2B I deleted and then undeleted it.  It is there again.

Answer (score 2):

If Tom **is** a Maiar (or, just possibly, a Valar), he could just scoot back to Valinor if the Sauron situation got out of hand. Few Valar are concerned with the *elves*, let alone any of the Subsequently Born; it makes sense to me that their Maiar would show a similar lack of interest in the peoples of Middle Earth and their magical trinkets. The One Ring, the most powerful magical artifact in Middle-Earth, can barely hold Bombadil's attention for more than a few minutes; I suspect he's similarly uninterested in anything that isn't his forest or his wife.

Comment: Exactly.  He's got hot Goldberry sex to think about.  Sauron is irrelevant to him.

Answer (score 2):

Two words:  Goldberry.  Okay, I guess that's one word.  But still, if you came home to this every night, would you really care about anything else?

[image]
[Credit to Anne Wipf]

To paraphrase the Eels' song "Hey Man (Now You're Really Living)", when you're in love with a beautiful girl, everything else seems less important.

From Tom's point of view, as long as he has water lilies for Goldberry, he has everything he needs, and not much else matters to him.

[image]
[Credit to Jinx Mim]

Comment: Common sense and slice of life answers are not necessarily off topic or undesirable.

Comment: I have no recollection of ever using the phrase "slice of life".

Comment: I don't think this is adding much to the conversation.

Comment: While this answer might not directly address the question, it does remind us of the nature of TB. He does not care about the struggles of Gondor vs. Mordor. He has no interest in rings of power. But, based on his songs, he does care about Goldberry. Bringing lilies to her makes her happy and making her happy makes him content. Little else seems to hold his attention or focus.

Answer (score -2):

Tom Bombadil is a particular character Tolken enjoys and fit into the story line.  The Old Forest is his Domain on Middle Earth and he is all powerful there. Gandalf does not even recognize his full potential. Had Sauron gotten the One Ring, he would have had no choice but to co-exist with TB. He would not have been successful crossing into the forest boundaries are any successful attempt at polluting the forest. Tom's only concern is for a happy peaceful life with Goldberry. There would be no stopping him from having this or for anyone else he'd allow to reside with him.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Can you elaborate as to *why Tom Bombadil was so unconcerned about the fate of Middle earth*?

Comment: @amflare It kind of does. "*Had Sauron gotten the One Ring, he would have had no choice but to co-exist with TB.*" - this answer is saying that Tom Bombadil would have been fine no matter what happened, so he had no need to care about stopping Sauron.

Comment: I did answer the question. TB had no interest or purpose to involve himself with the Ring. His sole interest was watching over the Old Forest. TB was uneffected regarding the Fate of Middle Earth. No matter what happened, the Old Forest would have remained unchanged.

Comment: This is a useful answer in that it adds information about Tom Bombadil.