# What would have happened to Tom Bombadil under Sauron's rule?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, tom-bombadil

As is well known and as was stated in a few answers on this site (see e.g. [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91451/why-was-tom-bombadil-so-unconcerned-about-the-fate-of-middle-earth)), Tom Bombadil was unconcerned about the War of the Rings and whether or not Sauron was defeated.

Tolkien himself put it this way:

> I might put it this way. The story is cast in terms of a good side, and a bad side, beauty against ruthless ugliness, tyranny against kingship, moderated freedom with consent against compulsion that has long lost any object save mere power, and so on; but both sides in some degree, conservative or destructive, want a measure of control. but if you have, as it were taken 'a vow of poverty', renounced control, and take your delight in things for themselves without reference to yourself, watching, observing, and to some extent knowing, then the question of the rights and wrongs of power and control might become utterly meaningless to you, and the means of power quite valueless. It is a natural pacifist view, which always arises in the mind when there is a war.
>
> *The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien* 144

But do we know what would have actually happened to him if Sauron ended up ruling Middle-earth? It seems not unlikely to me that Sauron would have feared him and would have tried to have him killed.

Did Tolkien ever mention what would have happened to Tom in such circumstances? Is there a way to estimate this based on things he had written?

Comment: I don't have time for a proper answer, but the relevant quote is from the Council of Elrond where it is pointed out that if Sauron were to win, Bombadil would succumb eventually, "Last as he was First".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found some evidence suggesting Tom Bombadil would not, in fact, have survived under Saruon's rule:

> Ultimately  only  the  victory  of  the  West  will  allow  Bombadil  to  continue,  or  even  to survive. Nothing would be left for him in the world of Sauron.

From Letter #144.

The only reason I don't consider this to be completely conclusive is that Tolkien might have been describing Rivendell's view on the matter:

> Tom Bombadil is not an important person – to the narrative. I suppose he has some importance
> as a 'comment'. I mean, I do not really write like that: he is just an invention (who first appeared in
> the  Oxford  Magazine  about  1933),  and  he  represents  something  that  I  feel  important,  though  I
> would not be prepared to analyze the feeling precisely. I would not, however, have left him in, if he
> did not have some kind of function. I might put it this way. The story is cast in terms of a good side,
> and a bad side, beauty against ruthless ugliness, tyranny against kingship, moderated freedom with
> consent against compulsion that has long lost any object save mere power, and so on; but both sides
> in some degree, conservative or destructive, want a measure of control. but if you have, as it were
> taken 'a vow of poverty', renounced control, and take your delight in things for themselves without
> reference  to  yourself,  watching,  observing,  and  to  some  extent  knowing,  then  the  question  of  the
> rights and wrongs of power and control might become utterly meaningless to you, and the means of
> power quite valueless. It is a natural pacifist view, which always arises in the mind when there is a
> war. But the view of Rivendell seems to be that it is an excellent thing to have represented, but that
> there  are  in  fact  things  with  which  it  cannot  cope;  and  upon  which  its  existence  nonetheless
> depends.  Ultimately  only  the  victory  of  the  West  will  allow  Bombadil  to  continue,  or  even  to
> survive. Nothing would be left for him in the world of Sauron.

It seems to me, however, the most conclusive evidence we have so far. I disagree with ibid's answer, since the quote in it refers to what would have happened if Tom had the ring, not if Sauron had won. The other answer, by jmoreno, seems to me like a good speculation, but it is still only a speculation. There is also a comment by Peter Cordes, suggesting that the case of Shelob might be an indication that Sauron wouldn't care about Tom Bombadil. This is also very interesting, although Tom and Shelob are fairly different.

Answer (score 35):

### Bombadil would have fallen at the end

During the council of Elrond they discuss sending the Ring to Tom Bombadil, and Glorfindel says that if Sauron were to get control he would eventually overcome the old forest as well.

> 'But in any case,' said Glorfindel, 'to send the Ring to [Tom Bombadil] would only postpone the day of evil. He is far away. We could not now take it back to him, unguessed, unmarked by any spy. And even if we could, soon or late the Lord of the Rings would learn of its hiding place and would bend all his power towards it. Could that power be defied by Bombadil alone? I think not. I think that **in the end, if all else is conquered, Bombadil will fall, Last as he was First; and then Night will come.'**
> <sub>The Lord of the Rings - Book II - Chapter 2 - 'The Council of Elrond'</sub>

Comment: Sauron has blood to spare. He can just throw endless armies against Tom's forest.

Comment: Tom is not the forest, and the forest is not Tom. The forest merely happens because of Tom's influence on the region. Of every Being in middle-earth, Tom is the least part of middle earth. He is merely there, not part of nor subject to the rules. Consider him a visitor of middle earth, a tourist, not an inhabitant.

Comment: @PcMan - Yet at the end he too will fall and the Night will come.

Comment: @ibid yep. Sauron would have extreme difficulty in affecting Tom, but Tom could only passively resist, not really oppose. Eventually he would be isolated, and his resistance would be meaningless, and he would pass. Consider how he utterly ignored the influence of the Ring.. Not resisted it, but *ignored* it. I always got the feeling (but no proof in Tolkien's writings) that Tom was a true Outsider, not one of Eru Ilúvatar's brood, who created Middle Earth. Being a "foreigner", he was not subject to the Rules.

Comment: This quote is talking about what would happen *if Tom had the Ring*.  Sauron would be motivated to get it from him.  Can we be sure that *if all else is conquered* also applies to / includes the case where Tom is totally uninvolved while Sauron captures the ring from the fellowship?  I think the question is still open of whether Sauron would choose to eliminate Tom if he regained his full power and was ruling over the whole of middle earth the way he ruled over Mordor.  At least without further justification to explain the reasoning.

Comment: "Fall" could, though, mean that Tom picks up and leaves Eä. He may not be able to *stop* Sauron, but it doesn't mean he can't run away.

Comment: @PeterCordes - True. The quote doesn't show if Sauron *will* conquer him, but it does still show that Sauron *could* conquer him.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting quote! However, as @PeterCordes noted, it seems to me this doesn't really answer my question, which was what *would* actually happen.

Comment: There simply isn't enough written about Tom Bombadil to know.

Comment: @chepner I think the other answer is pretty good.

Answer (score 12):

That would depend in part on others.  If Sauron had won, and Tom didn’t have the Ring, he would IMO probably have been left alone.  Tom isn’t someone to fear and isn’t someone it’s desirable to dominate, and he doesn’t have any resources other than the forest itself.

So, until the forest was desirable and worthy of his attention, there would be no need to deal with Tom personally and I don’t think his underlinings could.

The books describe what would happen if Tom had the Ring and Sauron came to dominate.  But that is with a great need, and IMO while Sauron’s greed and desire for dominion is unbounded, Tom and his forest aren’t something that Sauron would consider desirable.  To him, controlling all of the area around the forest and controlling all of the area around the forest + the forest would be the same thing.  It would be like a farmer that was dissatisfied with his control of his barn, not because it had rats, but because one particular rat didn’t hide quickly enough when he came by.

Comment: To support this, consider that Shelob is explicitly stated not to acknowledge Sauron as master. (scifi.stackexchange.com/a/94406/73281) Yet Sauron was happy to leave her alone, and even let her eat his own minions now and again. Perhaps he would be happy to keep Tom, and even exile naughty orcs to the Old Forest, to be eaten by the trees. If they're lucky! If they're unlucky, Tom might want to read them some of his poetry first.

Comment: @TimeTravellyParadoxySciFiSmeg: I thought about that afterwards, it could be very handy to have an inconsequential but impossible task handy.

Comment: @TimeTravellyParadoxySciFiSmeg - Tom was a Vogon?

Comment: @Dave - The question of _who or what was Tom Bombadil_ is highly debated on this website. I don't think there is a definite answer. But his poetry is, of course, the third worst on Middle Earth.

Comment: @TimeTravellyParadoxySciFiSmeg whose is the second worst? The Azgoths of Kria don't live in Middle Earth, do they? And didn't the very worst poetry perish along with its creator in the demise of Númeror? — Seriously though, Shelob is a good point to bring up but I'm not sure she can be compared to Tom here. Sauron might have kept her only because of the Ungolianth-Morgoth backstory... you know, _better give spiders what they want_...

Comment: @TimeTravellyParadoxySciFiSmeg Thank you for your comment! This answer along with your comment is as good as we're going to get, I think. It seems we don't have enough evidence to be completely sure, but it seems there is no reason to think Sauron would bother about Tom Bombadil, like he didn't bother about Shelob.

Comment: Perhaps one day someone will find more conclusive evidence, but, for now, I'll accept the answer; I doubt we'll get a better one. Thank you!

Comment: @leftaroundabout "Seriously though, Shelob is a good point to bring up but I'm not sure she can be compared to Tom here. Sauron might have kept her only because of the Ungolianth-Morgoth backstory... you know, better give spiders what they want..." - do you mind elaborating on this point? What is the Ungolianth-Morgoth backstory?

Comment: @Wade well, you should read the Silmarillion! — But ok, what happened is, Ungolianth wanted the Silmarils that Morgoth had stolen. When he wouldn't give those to her, _she attacked him_, and that was apparently such a threat – to Morgoth, Melkor himself! – that he needed the help of the Balrogs to fend her off.     Last time I checked, Sauron didn't have any Balrogs at his command, nor Dragons or anything on that level, so...

Comment: @leftaroundabout That's insane. Do you remember where that is in the Silmarilion?

Comment: @Wade chapter eight.